# Sort array of strings by custom rules per character class

Tags: java, sorting

today I meet a problem that sorts the ArrayList but when I use the default function array.sort() that the result can not meet my expectations. 
I need a sort of rules: number, alphabet, Chinese, other symbols,
but the default rules are ASCII code's order, so I try to override the compare function.

```java
private static String regEx="[`~!@#$%^&*()+=|{}':;',\\[\\].<>\\\\/?~！@#￥%……&*（）——+|{}【】‘；：”“’。，、？]";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        array.sort(new Comparator<NavigationNode>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(NavigationNode o1, NavigationNode o2) {
                if(p.matcher(o1.getName().substring(0,1)).find() && !p.matcher(o2.getName().substring(0,1)).find()){
                    return 1;
                }else if(!p.matcher(o1.getName().substring(0,1)).find() && p.matcher(o2.getName().substring(0,1)).find()){
                    return -1;
                }
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
```

if you have some suggestions please tell me, Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Well which problems do you have exactly? What order do you expect and which one do you get?

Comment: for example:disorder:['aaa,'1111','bbb','\aaaa','/aaaaa','中aaaa'],my expect order['aaaa','bbb',1111','中aaaa‘,'/aaaaa','\aaaaa']...

Answer (score 0):

That's what the Collator class is doing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

I'm not sure how it handles numbers and other symbols, it's main use is to sort non-ascii characters using rules from different languages. Collator implements Comparator<>, so you can use it as follows:

```
private static final Collator COLLATOR = Collator.getInstance(...);

array.sort(COLLATOR);
```

There's also a generic collator that can be used to mix different languages according to Unicode rules:

```
private static final Collator COLLATOR = Collator.getInstance(Locale.ROOT);
```

You can also write your own RuleBasedCollator, if necessary.

Comment: I appreciate that you can answer my question. but the COLLATOR by the Locale.ROOT is not to meet my requirements. But you give a method that I can create a Utils class that defines a kind of Collator which can suit more scenes.